# React useState with Typescript for setting a nested typed object

Tags: typescript

I have a burger menu, which will receive two props: 1) `isOpen`, and 2) a file object `{ name, type, size, modifiedAt, downloadUrl }`

I'm trying to do something like this, but Typescript is complaining

```
const FileManagerSlide = () => {
  const [burger, setBurger] = useState({
    isOpen: false,
    file: {
      name: null,
      modifiedAt: null,
      size: null,
      type: null,
      downloadUrl: null
    }
  });


  ...

                  <Tr
                  onClick={() =>
                    setBurger({
                      isOpen: true,
                      file: {
                        name: "HR STUFF",
                        modifiedAt: "01/03/2019",
                        size: 40,
                        type: "folder",
                        downloadUrl: "www.google.com"
                      }
                    })
                  }
                >
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/file-manager/file-manager-slide.tsx:287:31
    TS2345: Argument of type '{ isOpen: true; file: { name: string; modifiedAt: string; size: number; type: string; downloadUrl...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<{ isOpen: boolean; file: { name: null; modifiedAt: null; size: null; type: null; d...'.
  Type '{ isOpen: true; file: { name: string; modifiedAt: string; size: number; type: string; downloadUrl...' is not assignable to type '(prevState: { isOpen: boolean; file: { name: null; modifiedAt: null; size: null; type: null; down...'.
    Type '{ isOpen: true; file: { name: string; modifiedAt: string; size: number; type: string; downloadUrl...' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: { isOpen: boolean; file: { name: null; modifiedAt: null; size: null; type: null; downloadUrl: null; }; }): { isOpen: boolean; file: { name: null; modifiedAt: null; size: null; type: null; downloadUrl: null; }; }'.
```

I'm wondering if I define a `File` type and cast the file attribute of the burger state as that that it would work?

```
interface File {
  name: string;
  modifiedAt: string;
  size: number;
  type: string;
  downloadUrl: string;
}
```

However I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go with something like this:

Define a type for a "file" property in your component state.

```
type TFile={
   name?:string,
   modifiedAt?:string,
   size?:number,
   type?:string,
   downloadUrl?:string
 }
```

All properties are marked as optional.

In your component function specify a type for the "file" property

```
const [burger,setBurger]=React.useState({
    isOpen:false,
    file:{} as TFile
  })
```

We can set file property to be empty object as all properties are optional and ts will not complain. But this means name, size and other properties will be undefined (not "null" as you wrote). If you need them to be "null" you will need to modify the `TFile` type

You could go with a alternate syntax and write

```
 file:<TFile>{}
```

but unfortunately inside a `tsx` file you can only use "as TFile" syntax.

after this typescript should not complain when you set the state in your click handler:

```
setBurger({isOpen:false, file: {
                    name: "HR STUFF",
                    modifiedAt: "01/03/2019",
                    size: 40,
                    type: "folder",
                    downloadUrl: "www.google.com"
                  }}) -->>should be ok
```